# Azure service bus with session enabled integration with durable function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-durable-functions

I have one Service Bus Queue with session enabled.
I want to process all the messages which shares the same session id in one go every 8 hour and create a new message after aggregating all the messages from the session virtual queue and push this message to a new service queue.
The message will be processed by a new Azure durable function(using durable function as this is a long running process).

**High level diagram**

**[image: High level diagram]**

1. How Azure function will process all the messages of a particular session in one go to create a new message?
2. I want to complete the messages once all the processing of messages are done. How to do that?
3. How to complete message from the durable function?
4. If client function calls orchestrator function and completes, the lock will be released and the message will be visible to other instance of client function but it is currently being processed by orchestrator function. How to make sure the message is not visible to other client function as it is in processed state?

Comment: Not sure how big will be your aggregated message but servicebus has a limit on the message maz size. Why not ingesting all the messages, storing them in table storage and having a timer trigger function that will run every 8 hours and process all the stored messages  group by sessionID ?

Comment: @thomas message will not be big, aggregated message is map of key, value pair. At max the map will have 1000 key,value pairs. I am not using table storage because I don't want to manage it. second thing is i want messages sharing the same session id in order. If I use table storage then I will have to take care of the auto-scale. Using session enabled queue is giving me messages for each session in order.

Comment: Table storage is a managed service. Durable function is using it for orhcestrating function. My point was more about ingesting the message in order using servicebus, storing them then every 8 hours, having a function that will aggregate the messages.

Comment: @Thomas I have one doubt. Are you saying to use a separate table storage for the data ingestion or you are asking to ingest the data in table storage which is allocated to the durable function?

Comment: I was thinking using a dedicated table to ingest data then you can process them later on.